# 4WD Arduino sketch problem

Tags: arduino-uno

Here is the code:

```cpp
/**  * @file         Arduino UNO Autonomous Robot  * @author       Calin Dragos for intorobotics.com  * @version      V1.0  * @date
      13.10.2016  * @description  This is an Arduino sketch for an autonomous robot able to detect and avoid obstacles  */
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
Servo myservo;
int ENABLE_A = 6;
int PIN_A1 = 3;
int PIN_A2 = 2;
int ENABLE_B = 11;
int PIN_B1 = 5;
int PIN_B2 = 4;
int SENSOR_DISTANCE;
int LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
int RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
int SNZ_DISTANCE_L;
int SNZ_DISTANCE_R;
int LFT_SNZ_DIS;
int RGT_SNZ_DIS;
#define TRIG_PIN 7
#define ECHO_PIN 8
#define MIN_DISTANCE 40
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
#define INTERVAL 200
NewPing sonar(TRIG_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //pin mode for the DC motors
  pinMode (ENABLE_A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PIN_A1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PIN_A2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode  (ENABLE_B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PIN_B1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (PIN_B2, OUTPUT);
  //pin mode for the ultrasonic sensor
  pinMode(TRIG_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);
  //for servo motor
  myservo.attach(9);
  //set the ultrasonic sensor to center
  sensorCenter();
  //stop the motors
  stopMotors();
}


void loop() {
  SENSOR_DISTANCE = sensorDistance();
  Serial.print("Front sensor distance is: ");
  Serial.println(SENSOR_DISTANCE);
  if (SENSOR_DISTANCE >= MIN_DISTANCE || SENSOR_DISTANCE == 0) {
    goForward();
    Serial.println("Go forward");
  }
  else {
    //stop the motors
    stopMotors();
    LFT_SNZ_DIS = toTheLeft();
    RGT_SNZ_DIS = toTheRight();
    if (LFT_SNZ_DIS >= MIN_DISTANCE && LFT_SNZ_DIS >= RGT_SNZ_DIS)
    {
      int NEW_SNZ_DIS_LFT;
      //try three times to escape
      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        goLeft();
        Serial.println("Go left");
        delay(300);
        //stop the motors
        stopMotors();
        NEW_SNZ_DIS_LFT = sensorDistance();
        if (NEW_SNZ_DIS_LFT >= MIN_DISTANCE)
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      sensorCenter();
    }
    else if (RGT_SNZ_DIS >= MIN_DISTANCE && RGT_SNZ_DIS >= LFT_SNZ_DIS)
    {
      int NEW_SNZ_DIS_RGT;
      //try three times to escape
      for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
        goRight();
        Serial.println("Go right");
        delay(300);
        //stop the motors
        stopMotors();
        NEW_SNZ_DIS_RGT = sensorDistance();
        if (NEW_SNZ_DIS_RGT >= MIN_DISTANCE)
        {
          break;
        }

      }
      sensorCenter();
    }
    else
    {
      goBackward();
      Serial.println("Go backward");
      delay(500);
      //stop the motors
      stopMotors();
      sensorCenter();
    }
  }
}


void stopMotors() {
  analogWrite (ENABLE_A, 0);
  analogWrite (ENABLE_B, 0);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A2, LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B2, LOW);
}


int sensorDistance() {
  int distance;
  int uS = sonar.ping();
  distance = uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;
  if (distance != 0) {
    return distance;
    delay(300);
  }
}


void goForward() {
  analogWrite (ENABLE_A, 255);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A2, LOW);
  analogWrite (ENABLE_B, 255);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B2, LOW);
}


void goBackward() {
  analogWrite  (ENABLE_A, 180);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A2, HIGH);
  analogWrite (ENABLE_B, 180);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B2, HIGH);
}


void goLeft() {
  analogWrite  (ENABLE_A, 180);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite  (PIN_A2, LOW);
  analogWrite (ENABLE_B, 180);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B1,  LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B2, HIGH);
}


void goRight() {
  analogWrite  (ENABLE_A, 180);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A1, LOW);
  digitalWrite (PIN_A2, HIGH);
  analogWrite (ENABLE_B, 180);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (PIN_B2, LOW);
}


void sensorCenter() {
  myservo.write(90);
  delay(500);
}


void turnSensorLeft() {
  myservo.write(120);
  delay(500);
}


void turnSensorRight() {
  myservo.write(60);
  delay(500);
}


int leftSensorDistance() {
  int LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
  LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE = sensorDistance();
  return LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
}


int rightSensorDistance() {
  int RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
  RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE = sensorDistance();
  return RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
}


int toTheLeft() {
  int LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
  turnSensorLeft();
  LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE = leftSensorDistance();
  Serial.print("Left sensor distance is: ");
  Serial.println(LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE);
  return LEFT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
}


int toTheRight() {
  int RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
  turnSensorRight();
  RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE = rightSensorDistance();
  Serial.print("Right sensor distance is: ");
  Serial.println(RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE);
  return RIGHT_SENSOR_DISTANCE;
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Arduino: 1.8.6 Hourly Build 2018/05/28 09:33 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
In file included from C:\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:257:0,
                 from sketch\intorobotics.ino.cpp:1: C:\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard/pins_arduino.h:57:19:
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
#define PIN_A1 (15)
                   ^ C:\Users\Zeeshan786\Documents\Arduino\intorobotics\intorobotics.ino:17:5:
note: in expansion of macro 'PIN_A1'
int PIN_A1 = 3;
     ^ C:\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard/pins_arduino.h:57:19:
error: expected ')' before numeric constant
#define PIN_A1   (15)
                   ^ C:\Users\Zeeshan786\Documents\Arduino\intorobotics\intorobotics.ino:17:5:
note: in expansion of macro 'PIN_A1'
int PIN_A1 = 3;
     ^ C:\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard/pins_arduino.h:58:19:
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
#define PIN_A2 (16)
                   ^ C:\Users\Zeeshan786\Documents\Arduino\intorobotics\intorobotics.ino:18:5:
note: in expansion of macro 'PIN_A2'
int PIN_A2 = 2;
     ^ C:\arduino-nightly\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard/pins_arduino.h:58:19:
error: expected ')' before numeric constant
#define PIN_A2   (16)
                   ^ C:\Users\Zeeshan786\Documents\Arduino\intorobotics\intorobotics.ino:18:5:
note: in expansion of macro 'PIN_A2'
int PIN_A2 = 2;
     ^ exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: I was going to answer your question but instead I had to spend that time cleaning up the garbage formatting you dumped on us by using quote markup instead of code markup on your code and error message. Super disrespectful to the people you're asking for free help.

Comment: I'm so sorry....I tried but was getting bold and heading texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've chosen names for your variables that are being used by the core.  Pick different names for those variables.